# sentry react-native performance not recording anything

Tags: sentry, react-native-sentry

I am using “@sentry/react-native”: “^2.1.0” and trying to enable performance monitoring but so far nothing gets sent. According to the docs, doing tracesSampleRate: 1.0, in the initialization is all it takes. Is there anything else needed? Configuration in the dashboard (i saw the number 300 under Performance in the settings but I don’t know what it means exactly).

So far, I am using the app normally but not seeing anything in the performance part of the dashboard. I have tired executing methods that take more than 20 seconds to 1 minute…nothing changes. What kind of events does it take? or how i can simply stimulate some action that can be shown in performance dashboard?

Answer (score 0):

Version 2.1.0 includes the Performance Monitoring API but doesn't start a transaction automatically. You need to use the API to start and finish a transaction.

There [are docs on how to do that here](https://docs.sentry.io/platforms/react-native/performance/capturing/manual/).

The next version (due to next week) will include auto instrumentation if you're using the routers React Navigation v4 or v5. And it'll include spans automatically for `fetch` and `xhr` requests.

If you're not using either of those routers, you can continue to call `startTransaction` programatically and the `fetch/xhr` integrations will add the spans to the transaction.

You can follow the [GitHub repository for updates (like releases)](https://github.com/getsentry/sentry-react-native) to keep up with the additions. More routers and integrations will follow like [React Native Navigation from Wix](https://github.com/wix/react-native-navigation).

There's also a dev community on [Sentry's Discord that you can use to discuss developing integrations](https://discord.gg/PXa5Apfe7K) with Sentry and other SDK related topics.

[image]

Comment: ...has it been released? I see the version is still 2.1.1 or it is in the beta one?